# How to import a pdf image in TKinter

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter

I have a pdf image `image.pdf` that I want to import as an image to a TKinter Label image.

The solutions on other questions is to convert the pdf as a jpeg or png and then import as an image. However, I do not want to convert since I prefer a vectorised image.

Here is a **MWE**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as font
from tkinter import Tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

fontcolor = '#3a346f'

class Resources(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)
            helv10 = font.Font(family="Helvetica",size=10,weight="bold")
            self.surfacesImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Graphics/test.pdf").resize((160, 150)))
            self.Graphic1 = Label(self, bg = "white", relief = GROOVE, image=self.surfacesImage, font = helv10, fg = fontcolor)
            self.Graphic1.place(relheight = 0.45, relwidth = 0.2, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.3)
```

When running the main file containing this frame I get the following error: `UnidentifiedImageError( PIL.UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file 'Graphics/surfaces.pdf'`

Comment: PDF is not an image.

Comment: @acw1668, under LaTeX, it is possible to save images in .pdf format as a standalone file. Put differently, I would like to display the contents of that pdf in a Label in TKinter.

Comment: You can put an image inside a PDF, but PDF itself is not an image.  To display a PDF using label, you need to convert a page in PDF to an image using module like `PyMuPDF`.